# Cannot resolve org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.30.Final

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

This error comes when Spring Initializer is used, and project is imported in the IDE.

Comment: There is far too little information to answer this. What does your pom look like, which error do you get etc. etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1) Open the pom.xml file.

Step 2) Search for the parent tag.

Step 3) In parent tag check the version tag for the version of Spring Boot.

Step 4) Downgrade the version to previous version of Spring Boot.

```
Ex: From 2.4.5 to 2.3.3.RELEASE
```

Step 5) Update the project, problem is solved now.

Comment: Why would downgrading be the solution... Generrally this is a resolution problem and it appears to be fixed by doing this as it will download the dependencies again.